# How do I programmatically read files from an ISO or disk image in powershell?

Tags: powershell, iso-image, disk-image

I would like to read files from an ISO disk image as part of a powershell script. Because this is an automated process and the disk will only be open temporarily, I would like to avoid allocating unnecessary resources like a drive letter if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to read from an ISO without allocating any drive letters (* see below).

```
$DiskImage = Mount-DiskImage -ImagePath $ISOPath -StorageType ISO -NoDriveLetter -PassThru
New-PSDrive -Name ISOFile -PSProvider FileSystem -Root (Get-Volume -DiskImage $DiskImage).UniqueId
Push-Location ISOFile:
# read files with the usual filesystem commands
Pop-Location
Remove-PSDrive ISOFile
Dismount-DiskImage -DevicePath $DiskImage.DevicePath
```

*The drive created by `New-PSDrive` is not a real Windows drive, and will not be visible outside of PowerShell, or even outside of the Powershell function where `New-PSDrive` was run. The `Remove-PSDrive` call may not even be necessary if you are not using the above multiple times in one scope.

Comment: It's inaccessible outside of the PowerShell prompt due to the -NoDriveLetter parameter.

Comment: @Ramhound That is the intention, the disk is only used by the script so there's no reason to make it visible elsewhere.